# Scaling Application for video decoding using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, cpu, streaming, rtsp

I am building an application to read multiple IP camera streams (rtsp) and run different Machine Learning Algorithms over it in real time. For each camera stream,

1. I spawn an ffmpeg process which continuously break the rtsp streams into frames and store them as images (JPEG). The streams use H.264 encoding. I am taking 1 frame every second as output.
2. Message queues corresponding to models are given the message containing location of the file.
3. Models keep on picking up the file and drawing inferences

The problem I am facing is the CPU usage by ffmpeg decoding process. For real time inference without any loss of frames, I have to beef up my server by a core for every 2 camera streams. Is there any optimization I am missing for ffmpeg?

I am using Intel Xeon Gold processor with Ubuntu 18.04 OS